# 'StartApp/StartApp.h' file not found

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I just followed all the steps to this: https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/iOS-Swift-InApp-Documentation

and I'm still getting the error "StartApp/StartApp. file not found and also the "failed to import bridging header."

I have followed all this steps. And also; I don't know if having another ad network chartboost in my app already will effect StartApp.

If you guys could help me I'd be very happy :D

Comment: When I click on the StartApp/StartApp.h file not found error, it takes me to the import statement: #import <StartApp/StartApp.h> in the bridge.

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem with the SDK but it has been fixed, so you should download it again and give it a try.